# Save Global variable or a php like session

Tags: xcode, string, session, variables, global

I'm working on my app but i need some help.
I need a 'php-like session' in Objective C (without using connection to the internet)
I've thought about global vars, but my app seems to reset them when reloading the view.
This is my current code

SecondViewController.h

```
@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController
{
    NSString * string;
}
```

SecondViewController.m

```
@interface SecondViewController ()

@end

@implementation SecondViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if (! [string isEqualToString:@"Hello"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Hello");
        string = @"Hello";
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Bye");
    }
}

@end
```

But everytime I reload SecondViewController the 'string' is reseted to its default value.
I'm looking for something that we use in php (a.e. $_SESSION['string'] = 'hello')

Comment: did you get the solution Maarten1909 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be helpful to you . It stores the values until unless delete the app from your device .

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

// saving an NSString
[prefs setObject:@"TextToSave" forKey:@"keyToLookupString"];

// saving an NSInteger
[prefs setInteger:42 forKey:@"integerKey"];

// saving a Double
[prefs setDouble:3.1415 forKey:@"doubleKey"];

// saving a Float
[prefs setFloat:1.2345678 forKey:@"floatKey"];

// This is suggested to synch prefs, but is not needed (I didn't put it in my tut)
[prefs synchronize];

**Retrieving**

NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

// getting an NSString
NSString *myString = [prefs stringForKey:@"keyToLookupString"];

// getting an NSInteger
NSInteger myInt = [prefs integerForKey:@"integerKey"];

// getting an Float
float myFloat = [prefs floatForKey:@"floatKey"];
```